# Issues with FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I recently met an issue when using method `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, and it didn't create an account on Firebase or report any messages.

I had surely connected my app to Firebase, enabled email and password in the Sign-in method tab of the Firebase Authentication section of the Firebase console and set the android.permission.INTERNET.Here is the code:

```
private void signup() {
    //Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Begin registering!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String email = id.getText().toString().trim();
    String password2= password.getText().toString().trim();

    if(email.isEmpty())
    {
        id.setError("Email is empty");
        id.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches())
    {
        id.setError("Enter the valid email address");
        id.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if(password2.isEmpty())
    {
        password.setError("Enter the password");
        password.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if(password2.length()<6)
    {
        password.setError("Length of the password should be more than 6");
        password.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(id.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Begin registering!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("FirebaseAuth","onComplete" + task.getException().getMessage());
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                Log.d("FirebaseAuth","onComplete" + task.getException().getMessage());
                String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(uid);
                storageReference.putFile(imageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>(){

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                                    String imageurl = task.toString();
                                    User user = new User();
                                    user.name = name.getText().toString();
                                    user.uid = uid;
                                    user.imageurl = imageurl;
                                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(uid).setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                                Intent intent1 = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                                startActivity(intent1);

                                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Registered successfully! ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }else{
                                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Registered Failed! ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });

                                }
                            });
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Upload error! Try again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }else {
                Log.d("FirebaseAuth","onComplete" + task.getException().getMessage());
                Exception exception = task.getException();
                if (exception != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"You are not registered! Try again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // Log the error or display a message to the user
                }
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"You are not registered! Try again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword). When it comes to Firebase Storage, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose).